Why does my Time Machine restore inflate in size by double or more?
I made a brand new clean Time Machine backup of my 500Gb MacBook Air running Sonoma 14.6.1. which was using around 444Gb of its disk. I then installed Sonoma to a clean re-formatted 1Tb external hard disc, and tried to restore from the Time Machine backup. MacOS refused saying there was insufficient space. I then switched to install onto a 3Tb disk, selecting the option to restore from the Time Machine backup during installation. The install and restore completed. However, MacOS is claiming over 1.3Tb of the hard disc is being used. I had wondered if it was sucking all my iCloud data from Apple's servers but my iCloud account is not active on the new install. So what is taking up the space? With this behaviour my Time Machine backup is next to useless should I need to restore to my internal 512Gb SSD.

Have you actually looked through the restored data, to see what might account for the greater size? Either use comparison tools, or something like OmniDiskSweeper, which will sort the disks by size.
